# Gitlab key format issue

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

I am facing a strange situation where I am using gitlab account to handle my code. I am using ssh protocol to access the repo. I am able to pull the code but I am receiving the following error while I try to push the code. This could be something silly on my side. But *I have the keys stored in my gitlab profile* and *able to* use it to *pull the code*.

**Error :**

```
$ git push origin master
key_load_public: invalid format
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa':
Access denied.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: The passphrase you used while creating ssh key, you need to enter that and make sure that you have added that ssh key in your gitlab account. Even if it does not work. Create a new ssh key and add that in gitlab.

Comment: @PriyanshuShekhar, I have tried that option as well. Still doesn't allow me to push the code. How could the same ssh key allow me to pull the code but not push it ?

Comment: Have you used your ssh key in more than one git account in same system?

Comment: Are you sure you have exported the right file? How this key was generated?

Comment: @PriyanshuShekhar,  Nope, this is a brand new machine. I use this key only for this gitlab account.

Comment: @jaroslawj, I am sure that this is the right ssh key being copied to the user profile and I generated the key using puttygen and saved the public file (id_rsa.pub) and private file(id_rsa) at Users/username/.ssh folder and copied the generated key from the puttygen and pasted it into the ssh keys section of gitlab account.

Comment: Ok, so there may be two more issues: some problem with key cache - it should be cleaned after adding new keys and second key format: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/786

Comment: use `https` instead of `git@` to clone the repo. Then while pushing it wont ask for ssh key. It will ask for your credentials.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Finally I have been able to resolve this issue and I am posting it for other users. If the keys generated by **putty** is not helping you to access the gitlab repo, try generating the keys from **gitbash** terminal using the command `ssh-keygen` and save the files in `.ssh` folder of your user account.

The linux style key generation made my life easy as I was trying to generate key in windows environment with putty keygen.

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: This worked for my case, I had used putty-keygen and kept receiving the key_load_public: invalid format error. Solved it via generating the keys using the ssh-keygen tool from Cygwin.

Comment: Worked for bitbucket too.

Comment: I was directed to PuTTYGen by gitlab but this is the solution that worked for me. The gitlab help should be updated with this solution, esp. since it doesn't require an extra download.

Comment: Same for me on gitlab. Tried exporting key to OpenSSH from Puttygen but still didn't work. Using ssh-keygen helped.

Answer (score 18):

PuTTYGen can generate the correct OpenSSH keys.

1. Generate your key file, save the private key (with or without a passphrase)
2. Add your username/email address as the comment
3. Copy the contents of the generated key and paste it into your id_rsa.pub
4. Export the OpenSSH private key using the menu and save it as id_rsa

[image: Export OpenSSH Key]

Comment: What file do you load into the Putty Agent, PAGEANT.exe ?

Comment: @Leonel this isn't for the Putty Agent sorry

Answer (score 2):

I fixed my error by regenerating my public key (`id_es.pub`) from my private key (`id_es`) :

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_es -y > ~/.ssh/id_es.pub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "my.email@example.com"
AAAAB3NzaC1ycxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxx=
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

At the moment, you have to manually extract the key (removing the other lines) and add "ssh-rsa " in front of it. So it's like

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1ycxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxx=
```

It would be more convenient if Gitlab would do this automatically.

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/786

Answer (score 0):

If you upload 'vanilla' putty key, solution is probably described here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/786